# Excel Spreadsheet formulas for every 4th column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet that has a column in it which will return every 4th column of data from another spreadsheet. I've tried using the OFFSET command, but can't get it to populate correctly.

Can anyone tell me what formula I need to use?

Thanks.

Comment: Something with `=INDEX` would be the first thing I'd try, something with `=OFFSET` or `=INDIRECT` could also work, although without a concrete example, it's hard to give a concrete answer.

Comment: Ok, say this is the data I want in the following cells: In M2 of sheet 1 I want E20 of sheet 2. In M3 of sheet 1 I want I20 of sheet 2, in M4 of sheet 1 I want M20 from sheet 2, and so on. How do you use the Index function to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume in `Sheet2` you have the following data:

```
E20: This is E20!
I20: And here's I20
M20: Now, M20
```

Then in `Sheet1!M2` put:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$20:$20,1,(ROW()-1)*4+1)
```

Then select `M2:M4` and Fill Down. That will result in `M2` through `M4` having the values:

```
This is E20!
And here's I20
Now, M20
```

Here's how the formula works:

```
=INDEX(
```

We're going to use the `=INDEX` function.

```
Sheet2!$20:$20
```

The first argument to the reference form of `=INDEX` is the reference to pull data from. Here I've specified all of row `20` in `Sheet2`, but it could be a rectangular region, whatever, you could even use one of the other reference functions to calculate it. Changing it will require changing the 2nd and 3rd arguments to `=INDEX`, as described below.

```
1
```

The second argument is the row number *in the specified reference*. Here we want to pull data from the 1st (and only in this example) row in the reference, so `1`. If you change the reference so the desired data is in the 7th row of the reference for example, change this to `7`, etc. This can also be a formula if you want to calculate the row.

```
(ROW()-1)*4+1
```

The third argument is the column number, also in the specified reference. `=ROW()` returns the row of the current cell, so we take the row of the current cell (2, 3, or 4 in this example), subtract 1 (giving 1, 2, or 3), multiply by the period of the cells containing the desired data (so 4, giving 4, 8, or 12), and add 1 (giving 5, 9, or 13, which is column E, I, and M). If you change the reference or change which columns you want data from, this formula will need adjusting, but hopefully it should be fairly clear how to do that.